# Why we use $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ notation instead of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

I just realised, that I use all the time the notation $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, and all books and papers use $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
$\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is more sympathetic for me, because I always imagine a matrix like $\mathbb{R}^n$ $m$ times. And because we use the notation $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^m$, thats why I used $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ all the time.

Now I think I will change my practice, because I don't want diverge from the standards, but can anybody give me a reason for this habit?

Comment: $m$ comes before $n$ in the alphabet, so lots of people think it more natural for $m$ to come before $n$ if both are used as indices or exponents like this.

Comment: I think focusing on which letters are used in which order is missing the important point.  When we write $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ we conventionally mean $m\times n$ real matrices, i.e. $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  If you want to swap the appearances of $m$ and $n$, there's no confusion.  $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ denotes $n\times m$ real matrices ($n$ rows and $m$ columns).  So put the variables in whatever order you please.  The only convention here is the first variable counts the rows and the second variable counts the columns.  It's an arbitrary convention, but useful even so.

Comment: @hardmath I plead for $\mathbb{R}^{r\times c}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely because in the alphabet, $m$ precedes $n$.

Comment: Yes, but we use $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^m$, but maybe that is because _n_ comes from _natural_.

Comment: I disagree (with the comment).  $m,n$ are both used for natural  numbers, and I see $\mathbb{R}^m$ frequently.

Comment: I have also seen $\mathbb{R}^d$. $d$ refers to the dimension

Comment: @user153012 - yeah, you're right. I frequently use $\mathbf{R}^n$ instead of $\mathbf{R}^m$.

Comment: @vadim123 Most lowercase letters of the alphabet can be used for natural numbers except for $o$, as it looks like $0$ sometimes.

Comment: In old-style Fortran, variables starting with  I, J, K, L, M or N are used for integers, all other letters for reals.  If you're not writing Fortran, any letters can be used for whatever you want.